# How to rerender only the updated row using react-table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-table

I am trying to implement an editable data grid using react-table. The code looks something like below:

```
<ReactTable
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
/>
```

The problem I am facing is whenever a cell value in a specific row is updated the entire visible page is re-rendered.

Here is [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxo5xxn46) from the creator of the library that illustrates the problem.

I am thinking if react-table re-renders the entire page anytime there is an update in a single cell, then it is rather inefficient. Or I am not sure if I am missing something.

Any help us much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note: just because you're logging "row render called" in the Cell callback does not necessarily mean that the DOM was re-rendered. It will only re-render if the output of `render` is different from the previous.

In this case it *is* different, for every row, because you're calculating a `new Date` for every row. You need a way to check which row is the one being updated and only return a new date for that one.

Comment: When my testing my application I found that Cell function is called once per row, every time there is a change any where in the grid. Essentially, to prove that the entire page is re-rendered, I am using the timestamps as it was bit complex to debug in sandbox.

Comment: I have gone through react-table source code and figured that it generates key for row-group div (trGroup). As a result only the rows that are "actually" updated are re-rendered.